# how to save API xml request and response files

Tags: magento-enterprise, xml, soap-api-v2

I want to save magento customer(or other module) API(V1,V2) request and response XML files. for this i have found usefule [link][<strike>http://www.techytalk.info/magento-extension-for-logging-soap-v1-and-v2-api-requests/</strike>][1](http://www.techytalk.info/magento-extension-for-logging-soap-v1-and-v2-api-requests/), it uses

```
public function call($sessionId, $apiPath, $args = array())
    {
        Mage::helper('inchoo_soaplogger/v1')
            ->logPostXml();

        return parent::call($sessionId, $apiPath, $args);
    }
```

With this i can save request xml file, but i could not achieve response xml file, we do not have method `callResponse` to call from parent.

Please help me on how to save both response and request API XML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the SOAP cals go through the method `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap::run`

there is an if-else statement in there. The `if` branch generates the WSDL, you don't need to log that.
On the `else` branch you get the response as XML from the line `$this->_soap->handle()`.
Log that response.

For the xmlrpc calls everything passes through `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Xmlrpc::run`.
And the response is generated by the code `$this->_xmlRpc->handle()`.

Comment: I have used `Mage::log($this->_soap->handle(),null,'wsdl.log');` and `Mage::log($this,null,'wsdl.log');` but i could not see any log file

Comment: I could log `Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Adapter_Soap::run` method, but its giving wsdl structure, but i want in `XML` structure, how to acheive in `XML` format.

Comment: on the `else` branch you should not get the wsdl. you should get the response.